# How to use static library in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, static-libraries

i m having trouble in setting this up. I have created libTest.dylib but I m not able to use this in my iPhone app. It gives me an error "test.h : No such file or directory". How can I use this library in my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static library extension is .a

You have a dynamic library and you can't use it on iPhone

Look at this tutorial http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/

Answer (score 0):

IOS does not support dynamic library except standard Apple library. So First you have to convert code in to static library. an static library should support i386, armv6, armv7 architecture.

- i386 - For simulator.
- armv6, armv7 - device.